# image recognition library for detecting colors

Tags: image-processing

I am looking for a library that could help extract things like Hair Color, Skin Color, color of Top, Jean etc. Any recommendations? Ideally a Java Lib. So essentially, given an image, outputs the above colors.

Answer (score 2):

There's [ImageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/), which boasts to be the

```
world's fastest pure Java image processing program
```

It can be used as a library in another application. It's architecture is not brilliant, but it does basic image processing tasks.

Another good alternative: http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/en/index.html